# Performance of ES6 imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

In the [React Bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#importing), it is suggested that modules be imported individually from single distribution files rather than from the larger distribution file.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

// or less ideally
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Why is the second method less ideal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As that link says:

> You should import individual components like: `react-bootstrap/Button` rather than the entire library. Doing so pulls in only the specific components that you use, which can significantly reduce the amount of code you end up sending to the client.

If you import from `react-bootstrap`, the client will have to download *everything* in `react-bootstrap`. That could end up being quite a large chunk of code. In contrast, if you import from the `react-bootstrap/Button`, *all* that needs to be downloaded is the button - nothing extraneous is included.

Compare the file:

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Button.js

to

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.js

As you can see, importing from the Button requires a few imports:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { useBootstrapPrefix } from './ThemeProvider';
import SafeAnchor from './SafeAnchor';
```

But importing from the `index.js` requires a very large number of imports, **77**, to be precise.

```
export Accordion from './Accordion';
export AccordionToggle, { useAccordionToggle } from './AccordionToggle';
export AccordionCollapse from './AccordionCollapse';
export Alert from './Alert';
export Badge from './Badge';
// and 72 more
```

If you import from `index` instead of from `Button`, you're downloading a *lot* of code that you don't need, for no good reason.